# PHP - Split Multidimensional Array by key/value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to convert this  multidimensional array:

```
array(
[0] => array (
   "interest_income-bank" => "520.541"
   "total_interest_expense" => "145.791"
   "net_interest_income" => "434.937"
   "loan_loss_provision" => "135.664"
   .
   .
)
[1] => array (
   "interest_income-bank" => "617.894"
   "total_interest_expense" => "205.508"
   "net_interest_income" => "506.510"
   "loan_loss_provision" => "120.586"
   .
   .    
)
)
```

to an array like this:

```
array(
[interest_income-bank] => array (
   "0" => "520.541"
   "1" => "617.894"
   .
   .
)
[total_interest_expense] => array (
   "1" => "145.791"
   "2" => "205.508"
   .
   .
)
)
```

Tried a lot with no luck :(

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate the outer array, then the inner arrays. Add each value to an indexed array in your result.

```
foreach ($your_array as $sub_array) {
    foreach ($sub_array as $key => $value) {
        $result[$key][] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't have to iterate the full array, you only need to iterate one subarray and use array_column to grab all values in the full array.

```
Foreach($arr[0] as $key => $val){
    $res[$key] = array_column($arr, $key);
}
```

See it here: https://3v4l.org/SAZJd

If the array is larger than what you showed here (your dots suggest that I think).
This method will be much much faster than looping every single value of the array.

Comment: just love [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) - remember it was introduced in php 5.5