# How to split multidimensional array into multiple array dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got multidimensional arrays i want it to break into multi array in one variable

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => John Davis
            [1] => Marie J
        )

    [work] => Array
        (
            [0] => employee
            [1] => none
        )

    [address] => Array
        (
            [0] => street 1
            [1] => street 2
        )

)
```

I want output to :

```
$array1 = array("name" => "John Davis", "work" => "employee", "address" => "street 1");
$array2 = array("name" => "Marie J", "work" => "none", "address" => "street 2");
```

and how to generate dynamically if values keys more than 2

thanks alot

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469966/php-split-multidimensional-array-by-key-value

Comment: Similar Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785355/convert-multidimensional-array-into-single-array#6785366

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Split Multidimensional Array by key/value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469966/php-split-multidimensional-array-by-key-value)

Comment: no guys please make sure i need the array key to be exact name, work, address, not digit 0,1,2,3

Answer (score 3):

Please try below code get output:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($outerArray as $outerkey => $outerArr) {
    foreach ($outerArr as $key => $innerArr) {
        $newArray[$key][$outerkey] = $innerArr;
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Functional solution

```
// make array of keys
$keys = array_keys($arr);
// combine it with data sets 
$res = array_map(function (...$x) use($keys) 
       { return array_combine($keys, $x); },
       ...array_values($arr));
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/953017)